# Im getting "Apple Mach-O Linker Error" when running application

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5

Can someone tell me why I am getting
 
    `Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ScramblerModel", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

My project is at [This zip](http://www.scramblr.us/xcode/Scramblr.zip)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code clearly is referencing this `ScramblerModel` class, but you haven't included the `ScramblerModel.m` file in your project.

So, first, if you look at your `Compile Sources`, it says:

[image: no model included]

Go ahead and click on the "+" button at add your model. You probably want to do this for `ScramblerPlayer`, too, because you use that class, as well, so if you don't add that as well, you'll get another linker error.

[image: now added scrambler model]

Second, don't forget to tell the app what storyboard to use:

[image: storyboard]

Third, your .h has instance variables (ivars) defined for all of your `IBOutlet` properties. This is a problem, because your `@synthesize` statement is instantiating ivars with a leading underscore, but your .h (and your code) are referring to duplicative ivars that aren't hooked up to anything. For example, you have a property `remainingTime`, you have a `@synthesize remainingTime = _remainingTime` (which is creating a `_remainingTime` ivar). So your explicitly declared ivar `remainingTime` isn't connected to your `remainingTime` property, and thus no user interface updates will result if you use that ivar, despite the similar name.

You can fix the problem and simplify your code by (a) getting rid of the explicitly declared ivars for your properties; and (b) change your code to reference the property, e.g. `self.remainingTime` or the ivar `_remainingTime`. So, your .h is simplified and becomes:

```
//
//  ViewController.h
//  Scrambler
//
//  Created by Alex Grossman on 8/26/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 Alex Grossman. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class ScramblerModel;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
    ScramblerModel* gameModel;
    NSTimer* gameTimer;
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *high;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *skipButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *restartButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *playerScore;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *remainingTime;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *scrambledWord;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *guessTxt;

-(IBAction)guessTap:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)restart:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)skip:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)category:(id)sender;
-(void) endGameWithMessage:(NSString*) message;

@end
```

When you compile your project, you'll get lots of errors, though, because your code was erroneously referencing those old, redundant (and misnamed) ivars. Thus, for example, in your `viewDidLoad` you had lines like:

```
remainingTime.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", gameModel.time];
playerScore.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", gameModel.score];
```

Those should be:

```
self.remainingTime.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", gameModel.time];
self.playerScore.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", gameModel.score];
```

Just repeat this correction to everywhere you were referring to the erroneous ivars.

Comment: yea but now the simulator wont load

Comment: the application and just stays black

Comment: I just did but now my labels wont update to what there being told to do in ViewController.m, do you know why that is?

Comment: my labels still just say Label when i run the app

Comment: ok, i accept your answer but i dont have high enough reputation to +1 it, sorry

Comment: @AlexGrossman Glad you solved it. See my updated answer. Bottom line, the reason you shouldn't declare your instance variables for your properties is because of precisely this sort of mistake (where you have your explicitly defined instance variables, but your `@synthesize` is creating _another_ set of instance variables). The instance variables created by the `@synthesize` statement are good (with the suggested leading underscore). Just get rid of the explicitly declared instance variables for your `IBOutlet` properties.

Answer (score 0):

If you forget to add them to your projects Build Phases you will get the error "Undefined symbols for architecture i386". So add your implementation files to Compile Sources, and Xib files to Copy Bundle Resources.

```
Go to Scramblr Project -> Targets (Scrambl) -> Build Phases -> Complite Sources -> Add a ScramblerModel.m and ScramblerPlayer.m
```

Comment: why wont the simulator load the project now?